# External Transcend USB drive not detected

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

I have two Transcend USB drive enclosures. When they were purchased (in 2019) they were working fine all the time with different disks inside (HDD, SSD). But at some point, probably after some system update, they stopped working completely and are not even mounted. I use currently Kubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 9570. Drives are visible in **dmesg**:

```
[111851.908755] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[111851.957345] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=7000, bcdDevice=80.00
[111851.957351] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[111851.957355] usb 2-1: Product: StoreJet Transcend
[111851.957358] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: StoreJet Transcend
[111851.957360] usb 2-1: SerialNumber:             WL1J5AXN
[111852.008854] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[112321.441847] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[112351.943134] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[112351.991510] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=7000, bcdDevice=80.00
[112351.991516] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[112351.991519] usb 2-2: Product: StoreJet Transcend
[112351.991522] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: StoreJet Transcend
[112351.991525] usb 2-2: SerialNumber:             WL1J5AXN
```

and in **lsusb**:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8564:7000 Transcend Information, Inc. StoreJet Transcend
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 27c6:5395 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e301 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:671d Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

but not in **fdisk**:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E856D149-62E7-4FB3-ABA9-69D13C8600A2

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 976773119 975722496 465,3G Linux filesystem


GPT PMBR size mismatch (1953525151 != 1953525167) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device. This problem will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sda: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0825A324-D2CE-4466-8664-65C9CF9A13B7

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953519615 1953517568 931,5G Linux filesystem
```

The above output shows my two internal SSDs, but not the external HDD in the Transcend enclosure. "loop" devices are omitted for clarity.

I tried all the possible solutions suggested elsewhere, but nothing helps...

*Edit 1*

**sudo ls -l /dev/sdb**

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/sdb': No such file or directory
```

*Edit 2*

As suggested by @sudodus I tried booting from fresh Kubuntu 20.04 live USB drive, and the external drive is actually visible there! Still I don't see any way of making it work on my main system, other than installing everything from scratch

Comment: Please boot into a Kubuntu 20.04 *live* drive and check that this system (with software from April) can see the drives in your Transcend boxes. If that is the case, I think you have enough information to write a useful bug report (at Lauchpad). Otherwise go back to a live 19.10. If that fails too, I suspect there is a hardware problem, maybe in your computer's USB system.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the output of this command: `sudo ls -l /dev/sdb` when a problematic drive is connected and you are running the internal Kubuntu system.

Comment: @sudodus thanks for great suggestions, please see results above. It's already good that with your help I found some way to make it work on live USB system, but not sure what to do next to make it work on the main system

Comment: If your installed Kubuntu system is fully up to date after successful `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`, and it fails, I suggest that you create a bug report and provide the necessary data for the Ubuntu developers to identify and squash the bug (because I think some updated program causes the problem) It does help that you also write that it works in a live Kubuntu 20.04 LTS system. A developer may ask for corresponding data from when you run that with your faulty drive inserted ...  https://launchpad.net/

Comment: You need a user ID at Launchpad, and then run your installed system with your faulty drive inserted and run `ubuntu-bug ubuntu` in a terminal window.